# 2 loops 1 decremented variable

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have an assignment that calls for an input integer, it then decrements that integer all the way down to 1.

it must use a while loop to display that number all the way down to 1 and on another line use a for loop to do the same.

Now after I initiated the while loop, my output for the for loop does not display. Obviously because startNum is now set to 0 after the while loop.

How can I get around this so that I can display the decremented numbers on both lines?
Code I currently have:

```
public class CountDown 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");

        int startNum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("WHILE LOOP: ");

        while (startNum > 0)
        {
            System.out.print(startNum + " ");
            startNum--;
        }

        System.out.println("\nFOR LOOP:");

        for (int x = 0; x < startNum; x++)
        {
            System.out.print(startNum + " ");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: store the user input in a third variable say... userInput. Then set startNum to userInput before each loop.

Comment: Are you asking your school assignment here?

Comment: Mark W: Well that worked...I am over thinking this problem. Thanks for the assistance. 

DKSRathore: Unfortunately, while I'm assuming it is frowned upon...yes. But in this instance I was just asking what is wrong or missing in my code.

Comment: @ihaveacode I posted my answer just lemme know what you think about it

Comment: @DKSRathore [Homework questions are acceptable on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). What is off-topic (and what we usually see) is a) copy/pasted homework questions, b) no showing of code (because they usually haven't got any) and/or c) no specific issue (beyond what the homework question says). The OP here has not copy/pasted their homework, has provided their code, and has given a specific problem - all on-topic as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have another variable to reset `startNum` back to its original value, right before the `for` loop

```
// ...
int startNum = input.nextInt(); 
int reset = startNum;
// ...
startNum = reset;
for (int x = 0; x < startNum; x++)
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Java supports `OOP` and **primitives are passed by value** in `Java`.

why not creating a class and name it ,`Num` ?

```
public class Num {

        private int startNum;

        public Num() {

            startNum = 0;
        }

        public int getStartNum() {
            return startNum;
        }

        public void setStartNum(int startNum) {
            this.startNum = startNum;
        }
}
```

Dirver class become:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Num n = new Num();
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");

        n.setStartNum(input.nextInt());

        System.out.println("WHILE LOOP: ");
        int counter = n.getStartNum();
        while (counter > 0) {
            System.out.print(counter + " ");
            counter--;
        }

        System.out.println("\nFOR LOOP:");

        for (int x = 0; x < n.getStartNum(); x++) {
            System.out.print(x + " ");

        }

    }
```

output:

```
Enter a number: 8
WHILE LOOP: 
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
FOR LOOP:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

**do like this:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");

        int startNum = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("WHILE LOOP: ");
        int temp = startNum;           // store startNum in temp variable
        while (startNum > 0) {
            System.out.print(startNum + " ");
            startNum--;
        }

        System.out.println("\nFOR LOOP:");

        for (int x = temp; x >0 ; x--) {   // here iterate through temp.
            System.out.print(x + " ");

        }

    }
```